# The derivative of the absolute value |x|

Tags: calculus

I read about the derivative of the absolute value |x|, but
why the absolute value is not differentiable at point zero, and when it becomes 1 or -1 {geometrically}?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The derivative $f'(a)$ is said to exist at a point $a$ iff the limit

$\lim _{h\to 0}{\frac {f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}}$

exists.  That is, the limit as $h\to 0^-$ ($h$ approaches 0 from the left) should be equal to the limit as $h\to 0^+$ ($h$ approaches 0 from the right).

With this definition, it's easy to see why the derivative does not exist for $|x|$.  I'll leave this as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of thinking about the derivative is that it shows the *direction* of the curve at that point or, more correctly the direction of the tangent line to the curve.  If the curve happens to **be** a straight line, the derivative at any point is just the slope of that line.  But where there is a sudden change in direction, such as the 90 degree turn that occurs at x= 0 for |x|, there is [b]no[/b] such direction and, in fact, no tangent line.

In addition, while a derivative is not necessarily a continuous function, it can be shown that any derivative must satisfy the "intermediate value property"- that is, given any two values of x, say x= a and x= b, somewhere between a and b, f must take on **all** values between f(a) and f(b).  Of course, for x> 0, |x|= x so for x> 0, the derivative of |x| is the same as the derivative of x which is 1.  For x< 0, |x|= -x so for x< 0, the derivative of |x| is -1.  That is, |x| **can't** be differentiable at x= 0 because a function cannot take on all values between -1 and 1 at a single point!

Comment: Surely, you know that we use [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) to format our maths on this site...